# how to check is image inserted to database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, blob

i have a table in a database that have several rows and each row store an image and some  string

but some row have no image

i want to read content of this table to my android app and if image do not exist i show a default image

how can i check that image exist or not ?

this is my code

```
private void sql_load_data()
{

    byte[] illness_pic=null;

    Cursor cur_row;

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DataBaseHelper.DB_PATH+"/"+DataBaseHelper.DB_NAME, null, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    try
    {
        DBH.openDataBase();

        cur_row=sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select illness_name,illness_pic,illness_cause,illness_sign,illness_control from pistachio_illness where id="+id, null);

        cur_row.moveToFirst();

        lbl_illness_name.setText(cur_row.getString(0));

        illness_pic=cur_row.getBlob(1);
        imgviw_illness_pic.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(illness_pic, 0, illness_pic.length));
        lbl_illness_cause.setText(cur_row.getString(2));
        lbl_illness_sign.setText(cur_row.getString(3));
        lbl_illness_control.setText(cur_row.getString(4));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is nothing saved `if(illness_pic==null)` should be enough to check.

Other possibility is to add a field `HAS_IMAGE` and use it to check. Set it to `1` when you save image and to `0` when not save or remove it.

Comment: your if instraction not work and database is preloaded, i can not change it

Comment: what is not working? What do you have in the illness_pic when there is no image?

Comment: illness_pic is null when it have no image but if statement can't handle it, why, i don't know; i also check like `if(illness_pic.length!=0)` or `if(String.valueof(illness_pic.length)==null)` and .... but resault is same before and code do'nt work :|

Comment: try `if(illness_pic==null || illness_pic.length==0)`

Comment: this if statement worked: `if(illness_pic==null)` ; please add answer to this question to i confirm it, thank you